# TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, opencv, node-modules

TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined occurs in index.js of set-blocking in node-modules. Is there any way to solve it? or is there another way to use opencv in nodejs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined
    at :3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:168900
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/set-blocking/index.js.module.exports (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:168897)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:126738)
    at Object../node_modules/npmlog/log.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127102)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127799)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv-build/build/utils.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:128015)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127280)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv-build/build/dirs.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127306)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv-build/build/constants.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127242)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv-build/build/index.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:127599)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:128064)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:128136)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:128154)
    at Object../node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:128159)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Module.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1552)
    at Module../src/components/render.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2597)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/components/FaceFilter.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:148)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/components/App.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Module../src/index.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2627)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
    at Object.1 (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2873)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33)
    at :3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1
```

I get this error in console